# Sign in as different user when using Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I have restricted access to a site by using Integrated Windows Authentication and turning off anonymous access. This way I can then show them their real name (from looking up on Active Directory and using the server variable LOGON_USER) and do other related Active Directory tasks.

How can I then prompt again for their user credentials, through a 'sign in as other user' link , showing the browser prompt (like you would get on a browser like Chrome or Firefox, or if the site was not in the 'Intranet' zone in IE) rather than a Web Form?

Since SharePoint offers this functionality, I assume there is a way to do this through code, but I don't know what code can do this (using C#). I can send a 401 header which makes the prompt appear, but how do you then confirm if they are logged in?

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using Windows Authentication?

Comment: No, because you may want to do administrative tasks without having to log out of Windows. Windows Authentication is still used, but I want to switch between users without having to logout or do 'run as' on the browser executable. Since SharePoint has this functionality, there is some value in offering it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you out.

[ASP .NET – C# – How to “Sign in as Different User” like in Microsoft SharePoint with Windows Authentication](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=825)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. When I login, the LogonUserIdentity is still the same as before. In fact, it does not even authenticate - any username and password entered ends up redirecting back to the home page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. It is based on disassembled code of the method Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AccessDeniedPage.LogInAsAnotherUser()

First of all, I'm accessing the AccessDeniedPage page using javascript because Sharepoint does something similar:

```
function GoToSignAs() {
    window.location.replace("./SignAs.aspx?signAs=true&returnUrl=" + window.location.toString());
}

<a onclick="GoToSignAs(); return false;" href="javascript:;">SignAs</a>
```

Then, in your page AccessDeniedPage you use this:

```
public partial class SignAs : Page
{
    private const string LoginAttempts = "LoginAttempts";

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
        if (current == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        if (GetUrlParameter<bool>("signAs"))
        {
            HandleSignAs(current, GetUrlParameter<string>("returnUrl"));
        }
    }

    // ...

    private static void HandleSignAs(HttpContext context, string returnUrl)
    {
        int attempts = 0;
        HttpCookie attemptsCookie = context.Request.Cookies[LoginAttempts];
        if (attemptsCookie == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(attemptsCookie.Value))
        {
            attemptsCookie = new HttpCookie(LoginAttempts);
        }
        else
        {
            attempts = int.Parse(attemptsCookie.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]))
        {
            // Attempts are counted only if an authorization token is informed.
            attempts++;
        }

        if (attempts>1)
        {
            attemptsCookie.Value = string.Empty;
            context.Response.Cookies.Add(attemptsCookie);
            context.Response.Redirect(returnUrl, true);
        }
        else
        {
            attemptsCookie.Value = attempts.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            context.Response.Cookies.Add(attemptsCookie);
            SendEndResponse(context, 401, "401 Unauthorized");
        }
    }

    private static void SendEndResponse(HttpContext context, int code, string description)
    {
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        context.Items["ResponseEnded"] = true;
        context.ClearError();

        response.StatusCode = code;
        response.Clear();
        response.StatusDescription = description;

        response.AppendHeader("Connection", "close");
        response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Negotiate");
        response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");

        response.End();
    }
}
```

FIX: you must use the IIS to work properly